# How flatten transparency without rasterization?

Tags: vector, transparency, export, corel-draw, flatten

I have a simple illustration in CorelDraw with overlapping simi-transparent curves with uniform fillings, and I need to export it to EPS while maintaining everything in vector form. It is perfectly possible in principle since the illustration contains no gradients, only uniform fillings. By default CorelDraw rasterizes overlapping regions when exporting as EPS. After some trial and error I was [able](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280) to achieve this by exporting it to EPS from Adobe Acrobat or Illustrator with non-standard settings. But I would prefer to stay with CorelDraw. Is it possible in CorelDraw?

Comment: I haven't used CorelDraw before but its my understanding that when you save as CDR you can do so without any compression and then it will be able to be opened in Illustrator. Would this work for you?

Comment: @Ryan I have not tried to open CDR in Illustrator but saving it from CorelDraw to CDR does not allow to flatten transparency.

Comment: modern version of illustrator should be able to open CD files directly. however you could try exporting from CD as a postcsript file (PS - not EPS). this should open without any fill objections.

Comment: @stephencosh Good idea! It is necessary to save a .cdr file in a format of older version of CorelDraw for opening it in Illustrator CS6. I am not sure which highest supported version though.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be possible, depending on the artwork, but if you were to make a copy of the file and create shapes based upon the intersections by using any "shape intersection" tool or functionality and then fill those shapes with the closest solid color value to simulate the overlapped colors, then you will have vectors which will not need to be rasterized.

In simpler terms: a yellow circle which laps a blue circle, you have a yellow crescent, a blue crescent, and a green "ellipse."

The big drawbacks to this are: difficulty in incorporating changes; only works with solid fills; might not be manageable for complex shapes and layering.

Comment: I have solid fills with simple forms but there are too many objects to try to flatten them by hands. I need an automatic solution.